# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 backup _ fail

Tags: encryption

I am trying to mount encrypted drive.

Below is the volume information:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 976754646 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           1 4294967295 4294967295  16T ee GPT


ls /dev | grep sda

sda
```

I am confused... Why fdisk is showing `/dev/sda1` but there is no such device in `/dev` directory?